# solid line arrow vs dotted line arrow in class hierarchy diagram

Tags: java, class, interface, class-diagram

I'm currently learning java collection. I have been shown a class hierarchy diagram of `Set` interface and its sub-interfaces and concrete implementation classes.

[image]

No explanation was provided for the meaning of solid line arrow and dotted line arrow.

Using my own judgement, I assumed that solid line arrow means **extends**, and dotted line arrow means **implements**, but is my assumption correct?

Is there any official documentation for meaning and usage of such symbols?

Comment: All dotted lines go from a class to an interface, so my guess is that it means `implements` and a solid line means `extends`

Comment: hi @MarkJeronimus, thanks for the confirmation. Do you know any official documentation on the meaning and usage of such symbols?

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend. It also confirms my statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tagged this as [class-diagram](/questions/tagged/class-diagram). If you search for "class diagram" the first hit will probably be [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Class-level_relationships), where it is explained:

> - **Generalization/Inheritance**
>     It indicates that one of the two related classes (the *subclass*) is
>     considered to be a specialized form of the other (the *super type*)
>     and the superclass is considered a Generalization of the subclass.
>     The UML graphical representation of a Generalization is a hollow
>     triangle shape on the superclass end of the line (or tree of lines)
>     that connects it to one or more subtypes.
> - **Realization/Implementation**
>     In UML modelling, a realization relationship is a relationship between two model elements, in which
>     one model element (the client) realizes (implements or executes) the
>     behavior that the other model element (the supplier) specifies.   The
>     UML graphical representation of a Realization is a hollow triangle
>     shape on the interface end of the *dashed* line (or tree of lines)
>     that connects it to one or more implementers.

It is also illustrated with this picture:

[image]

So yes, your assumption in your example was right: solid line means it extends the interface, and dashed line means it implements the interface.